# Google+ account access from GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-gdk

I am looking for possible ways to make login functionality in my Google Glass app. Is there a way to access the Google+ account that every user is logged into using the GDK? I have read the available documentation and I cannot seem to find such a thing.

Am I missing something? Also, is there a way to access this using the Mirror API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a great way to do it right now.

When GDK was announced, there was reference made to an authentication API, but it is still in development. An early version is used by the Strava Glassware. When it is released, it will use a REST API much like the Mirror API to convey authentication information to your user's Glass. You will then be able to access it using the `AccountManager`.

In the mean time, you can work around this issue by sending authentication data to Glass using a QR code, but be ready to switch to the official solution once it is available.

Comment: Is that "early version" of an authentication API available to the rest of us to experiment with?